# Hex to HTML Conversion for special characters

Tags: html, utf-8, ascii

I am calling a service that will return the hex values for special characters. How can i convert those quickly to html ascii char codes either in java or javascript? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to look on the following websites.

http://unicodelookup.com/

http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html

I think the first one is what you are looking for, but the second one helps you converting sentences.